# How do I use two objects?

Tags: traducción, objetos-indirectos

A veces quiero decir algo como la siguinte oración en español

> Do you want me to invite you?

No sé cómo traducirlo. He tratado:

> Me quieres invitarte?

Pero no me parece bien. También he tratado:

> Quieres que te invito?

Creo que esto no es lo mismo.

¿Cómo digo mi oración original en español?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La traducción sería más bien:

> ¿Te gustaría que te invite?

Aunque, si he entendido bien el sentido de la frase en inglés, el objetivo de la frase parece darle a entender que podrías invitarle si él quisiera. En español solemos ser más directos, y más que preguntar por si quieres que te invite, se preguntaría directamente:

> ¿Te gustaría venir?

Comment: I think this answer fits more with the original meaning of my sentence, so I'm going to accept this one instead.

Comment: Las frases que propones son correctas, pero esa idea de que los hispanoparlantes sean más (¡o menos!) directos es algo que ningún lingüista serio comprobaría.

Answer (score 8):

> Do you want me to invite you?

La traducción literal sería:

> ¿Quieres que te invite?

Pero yo te recomendaría utilizar la siguiente expresión, que a mi parecer suena mejor:

> ¿Puedo invitarte?
>
> ¿Me permites invitarte? ó ¿Me permites que te invite?
>
> ¿Me dejas invitarte? ó ¿Me dejas que te invite?

Estas 3 frases serían la traducción para `May I invite you?` que desde mi punto de vista va mejor con tu propósito.